# NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore error: com.xxxxx.xxxxx has no valid com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier entitlement

Tags: xcode, in-app-purchase, entitlements

Set up MKStorekit, also have Share kit, my store is not in the root view controller.  I have security and storekit frameworks added and connected correctly, and am getting the following error:

```
NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore error: com.xxxx.xxxx has no valid com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier entitlement
```

Someone else had this error and was told to wait a few hours.  Well, I set up my products in iTunes Connect (they all say waiting for review) 3 weeks ago.  The bank account information is correct because I've deposited money into the bank account to make sure, and I've been careful to follow all the instructions.

My app has nothing to do with iCloud, and therefore iCloud is not enabled.

I've been struggling getting IAP hooked up for 3 weeks now, and am about to give up on xcode programming forever lol... plllllllllease someone help me :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there's a bunch of iCloud stuff in the MKStoreManger.m file, just commented it out and it fixed the error.  Still no store, but it doesn't appear to be due to this